# converted class to hooks getting 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at getFloorplan '

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn by coding here i converted classes to hooks, class version is working fine, but converted(hooks) version gives me this error :  'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at getFloorplan ', would appreciate any help.

here is working code:

```js
 import {
        getGraph,
        getFloorplan,
        changeActiveCamera,
    } from "../redux/actions";

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        currentSite: state.selection.currentSite,
        currentCamera: state.selection.currentCamera,

      
      };
    };

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        getGraph: (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site)),
        getFloorplan: (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site)),
           changeActiveCamera: (site, id) => dispatch(changeActiveCamera(site, id)),

      };
    }


    loadGraph() {
        if (this.props.currentSite) {
          this.props.getFloorplan(this.props.currentSite.identif).then(() => {
            console.log("Fetched floorplan");

            this.props.getGraph(this.props.currentSite.identif).then(() => {
              console.log("Fetched model", this.props.realGraph.model);

              // new camera-related node & link status
              if (this.props.currentCamera) {
                this.props.changeActiveCamera(
                  this.props.currentSite.identif,
                  this.props.currentCamera.identif
                );
              }
            });
          });
        }
      }
```

This is hooks version which i converted from above code, here i'm gettin that error:

```js
   const currentSite = useSelector((state) =>      state.selection.currentSite);
       const currentCamera = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentCamera);
       const getFloorplan = (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site));
       const getGraph = (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site));
       const changeActiveCamera = (site, id) =>
        dispatch(changeActiveCamera(site, id));
      
      const loadGraph = () => {
        if (currentSite) {
          getFloorplan(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
            console.log("Fetched floorplan");

            getGraph(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
              console.log("Fetched model", realGraph.model);

              // new camera-related node & link status
              if (currentCamera) {
                changeActiveCamera(
                  currentSite.identif,
                  currentCamera.identif
                );
              }
            });
          });
        }
      };
```

Comment: const getFloorplan = (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site)); isn't this recursive call without exit point?

Comment: @Singh how should i convert that class to hooks exactly ? how would you ? i'm missing something

Comment: @Singh in this video its done exactly same video without error: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-replacing-mapdispatchtoprops-with-the-usedispatch-hook

Comment: what i can see is that he is calling different function in dispatch(ratesUpdated); and not updatedRates.

Answer (score 0):

Change name of your constants or name your imports to avoid creating recursive calls.

```js
       const currentSite = useSelector((state) =>      state.selection.currentSite);
       const currentCamera = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentCamera);
       const dispatchGetFloorplan = (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site));
       const dispatchGetGraph = (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site));
       const dispatchChangeActiveCamera = (site, id) =>
        dispatch(changeActiveCamera(site, id));
      
      const loadGraph = () => {
        if (currentSite) {
          dispatchGetFloorplan(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
            console.log("Fetched floorplan");

            dispatchGetGraph(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
              console.log("Fetched model", realGraph.model);

              // new camera-related node & link status
              if (currentCamera) {
                dispatchChangeActiveCamera(
                  currentSite.identif,
                  currentCamera.identif
                );
              }
            });
          });
        }
      };
```

Comment: @joonas In my taste in last snippet I would avoid declaring consts at all and instead just use dispatch function inside your loadGraph function if possible.

Comment: yes you are right but it didnt work !! i tried that and got ' 'Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise'.ts(2339)'' , could you possibly add two answers one which you have already added and another that one which u just suggested ?

Comment: i found one problem here, with class version which works in console '              console.log("Fetched model", this.props.realGraph.model);' i'm getting 'Fetched model Object', but in your version i'm getting 'Fetched model undefined', any reason ?

Comment: and and now also getting 'Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>'.ts(2339)
'

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code realGraph variable defined so I cannot help you with that. Your original question was about stackoverflow issue regarding the infinite loop. Also from your code I'm not quite sure is it necessary to await for promise resolving from one redux action in order to dispatch another one. Are those async calls at all?

Comment: why it is not giving any error with that class version? if you were to convert that class version(first code with 'this' keyword) to hooks, how would you convert it ?

Comment: 1. case - this.props.realGraph.model  , 2. case realGraph.model.  What's different here? - this.props are! Where are your props, and are you sending them at all? Should you use props keyword maybe? We cannot know since we don't have your complete code here. I'm sorry but I gave you the answer for your initial question.  

check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Comment: just forget about this part 'realGraph.model', how would you convert the rest ?